# Reading a specific text in a file and assigning to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to **read/copy** a specific text from a file and assigning it to a variable. 
File(token.txt) contents are:

- Other file content *
- Other file content *
- Other file content *
- Other file content *
- Other file content *
  Mid-access token: eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IkNiNTFhalJ2THBOTF8ya20zZVA2WUxkbWYydldxUzJhdjh3VGdzVngxV0UiLCJ4NXQiOiJFV2pWcWc3MFoxQTNUcWNtUzhKZTg1blJ1cDgiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.T_aCXYzT4pThuKic2VEDbSKSc9Yl0upmjun62vPxdEBOYhCiMCbNA_jdFxd_ZVcegZICnQyl8KrD52MCpCjy5G_yMwEjTppnojcWv7FFIYMgpNu664jB4VPeGoiGJU7KH0EtpN6akKT5eSnlRunlqZd4FWSclDckaKhuPuKo8PPf2bzShGb4aH7obYik_RRbAiOf4z1vdM7JKYKo0Co6K1ZNkdZ3_K6hSOtHoNhHc6B6uay_D24T3nTHyllukTU4m4KsCzJfwFz407dNWk7niDTZVMXUn893_dIbxZ-WOCKgRpqupeb7ihmGbQ5C-JflP1iUScQ4tYM8EIpvm_dXvg

Build successful.

Here, I want to copy the value of Mid-access token from this file `"token.txt"` and would want to assign it to a variable called ttk.

Comment: You can use regax to get the value and varriable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file appears to contain the required token on the first line, so open it with [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and read the first line into a variable:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    ttk = next(f).replace('Mid-access token:', '').strip()
```

Now variable `ttk` will contain the token string. [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.replace) removes the prefix from the line and the [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.strip) is there to remove any surrounding whitespace such as the new line character from the end of the line.

**Edit**

It seems that the token line actually occurs towards the end of the file, always following the `Mid-access token:` line. Here is some code that will extract the token regardless of its location within the file:

```
ttk = None
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Mid-access token:'):
            ttk = next(f).strip()

print(ttk)
```

Comment: The token is at the end of the file and not at the beginning of the file. This code holds good for this scenario as well?

Token is in a single line the entire text after "Mid access token: ". The value should be read as a single line. The token is that long.

Comment: @deva.tester: OK, you have clarified, again,  the requirement. Please try to do that _before_ you post.

Comment: @deva.tester: I've updated my answer. It will now set `ttk` to the content of the line immediately following a line that starts with the text `Mid-access token:`

Answer (score 0):

To get contents from document add `open(token.txt, r)`

To save to file use

```
data=myfile.read().replace("mid-acess token:" "")
```

Print results

```
print(data)
```